# Reorder "sidebar" and "pager" divs in the generated html code

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, advertising, design, performance

*Sometimes* the http://ads.stackoverflow.com in

```
<div class="everyonelovesstackoverflow">
    ...
```

will delay (many seconds) to respond, thus "page numbers" and "footer" wont be rendered.
(I use Firefox v3.6 if that matters)

I suppose I could implement a Greasemonkey script for that job but I prefer it to be the *default* behavior :)
Wouldn't it be better if the sidebar was rendered last?

Comment: Out of interest, how often do you click stuff in the footer? and how often in the sidebar?

Comment: @Rich that's not the point, you can neither comment nor answer during those few seconds.

Comment: @Rich, as a matter of fact, I often navigate to other sibling sites from the footer nav.

Comment: @Rich, "page numbers" is what I want. Right now there is a navigation glitch that should be resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should no longer be an issue due to a change in the ad loading strategy.