# Failed to load source for: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/1234567/ivc/3c10

Tags: support

For some reason, on Stackoverflow posts, pages keep loading for 15 seconds until the request to this link times out(?). During this time I generally can't click on anything that has Javascript events associated with it. This only happens while at work so it may be a corporate firewall issue. I was just wondering if there was something I could do to remedy it because it's starting to get very annoying.

The Net tool in Firebug reports that the request comes back as a 204 (No Content) message.

(I'm not really sure how to tag this because I don't think it's a bug per se)

**Update:** The chat boxes on the right hand side don't show up until the 15 second mark. Disabling antivirus does not change the result.

**Update 2:** Could someone post the kind of result I should be getting so that I can determine if a firewall or something might be blocking it?

**Update 3:** This is the code that calls the resource:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/posts/1234567/ivc/3c10"></script>
```

Comment: The response itself expected behaviour, though I'm not sure what's up with the delay...

Comment: Would you happen to remember when you started noticing the 15 second thing?  Does it coincide with the time I noticed it (Nov-Dec 2010)?  It might just be something in the site which happened to be amplified by my antivirus.

Comment: @Jeff I believe it happened around the time they started using the HTML5 features for logging in. I am not positive about this though. It definitely has not always done this.

Comment: Is this still an issue for you?  I noticed [Jeff's answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41269/reorder-sidebar-and-pager-divs-in-the-generated-html-code/75099#75099) and re-enabled my AV.  It is no longer freezing 15 seconds anymore.  I had it this way since October so it might have been corrected way back then or just recently or something completely different.

Comment: @Jeff yes it is still doing this

Comment: Note: You're supposed to be getting a 204 No Content response, it's just a dummy request for the view counter mechanism.

Comment: just curious, do you have proxy server or something that translate/inject/remove some http headers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That link returns a [204 no content](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.2.5) by design, so I suspect your work firewall is configured incorrectly.

Comment: I think you're right.